# How do i get a value ( a hidden field in that page ) of a Referer page in the current page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-7, httphandler, httpmodule

I am using asp.net & the application is hosted in the IIS.  My requirement is, I want to get a value of the referer page, in the current page. i cannot use query string to send that value.

Scenario:
I have a page, Home.aspx which is having a hyper link, referring to Demo.aspx page. When clicking the link, i will be redirected to the Demo.aspx page. On page load of the Demo.aspx page, i can get the previous page url(with the query string), by using the HTTP_REFERER server variable. But i need to find a value in that referer page. How do i do this?

Comment: Passing the value as a parameter is the way you do that. The referrer page doesn't exist anymore when the client loads the other page.

Answer (score 3):

i can think of other options other than sending the value via query string:

- set the value as the session variable when displaying the first page (i would prefer this one)
- make the link (on first page) act like form and send the value via POST parameter
- set the cookie variable (on the first page) and retrieve it when displaying the second (visitor must allow cookies + the domain names must match this way)

Comment: If you need it in the frontend, you can save this value in a cookie variable. Or using localStorage. And retrieve it.

Comment: @samuel can you please give me an example of the last 2 methods.